# cleaning data with Python (for statement)

Tags: python

Edit: Sorry for the confusion everyone. The first version of this question is so confusing I that have decided to delete it.

Here is my question again.

How do I translate a list of 10,000 student names (text file) to a list that can be iterated through?

I initially said dictionary, but I actually meant list, I apologize.

Comment: i don't really understand you :) "They all refer to the same class", who's "They"? also "these data within these variables"?

Comment: I'm a bit confused too, to me it seems like you want a multi-dimensional dictionary unless it's incremented statistics for the classes then you would just CSV split each line (since you can define delim) and use `dictionary.has_key("Statistics_1101")` and if it doesn't have it, add it with a value of one, if it does, increment by 1.

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to get the names of all students in statistics classes, or do you want to get all the classes that someone is enrolled in, or do you want to do something else?

Comment: Please elaborate much more with code examples so we can help you.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I have rephrased the question to a more general question that hopefully can be understood :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that each student's name is on its own line, which is what it sounds like, this is as easy as

```
students = open('list-of-students.txt').readlines()
```

which will make `students` be a `list` of all the students in the file.

Comment: `list(open('list-of-students.txt'))` also works. It hardly gets any easier than that :) I would prefer to use a with-block to open the file, though.

Answer (score 1):

It depends strongly on what you want to do.

But something like this should work:

```
with file("filename-with-students.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
       ## now, the name "line" refers to a string containing a line in your file
```

The first line, `with file(...) as f`, opens the file and assigns the "file descriptor" the name `f`. Using a `with` statement means that it will automatically be closed when you're done.

The second line, `for line in f`, takes advantage that you can [iterate](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) over files, one line at a time. Hence, you can do whatever you want the string that `line` refers to.

Comment: If you actually wanted to build the list, you could just use `list(f)`. But this isn't needed for iteration :)